# Is it possible to run fb on one head and X on anohter, given one card connected to a TV and a monitor?

Tags: x11, intel-graphics, framebuffer, void-linux

I would like to set up so that my computer's monitor is connected to it's VGA output, while having a framebuffer on the other head.

Both heads seem to share a card.

They work fine as part of the same X display, but I prefer to have the TV not be treated as an X display, or at least to have head 0 be DISPLAY=:0 while head 1 is DISPLAY=:1.

It this possible, and/or a good plan?

```
    00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 8th Gen Core 8-core Desktop Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers [Coffee Lake S] (rev 0d)
    00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 630 (Desktop 9 Series) (rev 02)
    00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Thermal Controller (rev 10)
    00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller (rev 10)
    00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Shared SRAM (rev 10)
    00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH HECI Controller (rev 10)
    00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SATA AHCI Controller (rev 10)
    00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #8 (rev f0)
    00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #12 (rev f0)
    00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation H370 Chipset LPC/eSPI Controller (rev 10)
    00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH cAVS (rev 10)
    00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SMBus Controller (rev 10)
    00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SPI Controller (rev         10)
    00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (7) I219-V (rev 10)
    01:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR928X Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express)        (rev 01)
    02:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Intel Corporation Device faf0 (rev 03)
```

Comment: X can run on a framebuffer. Do you want two X displays, one for each device? Or one X display and one SDL framebuffer? Or one X display spread across both devices?

Comment: I would prefer one framebuffer, one X server, so I can use mplayer for the frambuffer to play movies and such.

But I'd be happy with 2 X servers.